# Imprimir lista de objetos en java

Tags: java, impresión

Estoy consumiendo uno servicio web que me devuelve una lista de objetos, la lista contiene 10 objetos y cada objeto contiene 5 atributos `nombre`, `placa`, `sexo`, `direccion`, `fecha`.

Lo que necesito es saber como recorro la lista y accedo a cada atributo de los objetos para hacer una serie de comparaciones.

Intente hacerlo con un `for each` pero simplemente me imprime los 10 objetos, pero no los datos que contiene cada objeto.

También lo intente con un iterador pero pasa lo mismo:

```
Iterator iter = MILISTA.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
  System.out.println(iter.next());
```

Así consumo el servicio web y vacío todo a la lista Lista `Comparendos`, Esta lista me queda llena con 10 objetos, cuando hago `debug` puedo ver los atributos de los objetos, pero no se como imprimirlos.

```
public void MtdConsultarComparendo(ActionEvent event) {

    ServiciosComparendos BBB = ClsSeguridad.ServiciosComparendos();
    ViewComparendoWeb XVARIABLEX = new ViewComparendoWeb();
    XVARIABLEX.setPLACA(getPlacax());
    setListaComparendos(BBB.getcomparendoWeb(XVARIABLEX));
}
```

Comment: deberias mostrar un poco de codigo para poder ayudar

Comment: Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Se necesita el código para el objeto que quieres imprimir.

Answer (score 5):

Para poder imprimir los atributos de los Objetos es necesario hacer un `cast` al Objeto a la clase Respectiva , dado que el método [Next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) de la interface [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) devuelve un Objeto.

Por ejemplo si los Objetos sería de tipo `Persona` , sería así :

```
Persona person ;
Iterator iter = milista.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
  person = (Persona)iter.next(); /* Cast del Objeto a la Clase Persona*/
  System.out.println(person.getNombre());/* Accedo a los atributos de la clase 
                                           por medio de sus Getters*/
}
```

Con el `For` sería algo similar :

```
for (Object obj : milista) {
  person = (Persona)obj; /* Cast del Objeto a la Clase Persona*/
  System.out.println(person.getNombre());
}

/* O hacer el cast directamente en el For */
for (Persona obj : milista) {
  System.out.println(obj.getNombre());
}
```

La Otra forma sería recurrir al método `toString()` como lo Explico @Stefan en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera para conseguir lo que quieres es hacer un @Override del método `toString()` en tu objeto conteniendo los datos.

Luego usas:

```
Iterator iter = MILISTA.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
  System.out.println(iter.next().toString());
```

Alternativamente puedes implementar un método en tu clase de objeto como `imprimir()` y usar genericos, si no quieres cambiar la representación por defecto como el objeto se muestra como String y usar:

```
public class Dato{
    public String nombre;
    public String placa;
    public boolean sexo; // true = m, false = f
    public String direccion;
    public Date fecha;

public void imprimir(){
    System.out.println(String.format("%s %s, (%s), %s, %tT",
        sexo ? "Sr." : "Sra.", nombre, placa, direccion, fecha));
}
```

Con código para imprimir:

```
List<Dato> MILISTA = new ArrayList<Dato>();
// poblar lista 

Iterator<Dato> iter = MILISTA.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
  System.out.println(iter.next().imprimir());
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una lista de objetos puedes optar por imprimir los objetos aunque no te daran mucha informacion, pero puedes imprimir alguna propiedad como por ejemplo el `nombre`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < MILISTA.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(MILISTA.get(i).getNombre());
      //System.out.println(MILISTA.get(i).getPlaca());
      //System.out.println(MILISTA.get(i).getSexo());
      //System.out.println(MILISTA.get(i).getDireccion());
      //System.out.println(MILISTA.get(i).getFecha());
 }
```

de la misma forma usando Iterator, casteando el elemento de acuerdo a tu tipo de Objeto:

```
while (iter.hasNext())
     System.out.println(((tipoobjeto)iter.next()).getNombre());
     //System.out.println(((tipoobjeto)iter.next()).getPlaca());
     //System.out.println(((tipoobjeto)iter.next()).getSexo());
     //System.out.println(((tipoobjeto)iter.next()).getDireccion());     
     //System.out.println(((tipoobjeto)iter.next()).getFecha());     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, debes usarlo de la siguiente forma (este es un ejemplo con `JDBCTEMPLATE`):

```
String query="SELECT nombre, correo, telefono FROM usuarios WHERE id ="+id;

        List<Map<String, Object>> apoyo=this.jdbctemplate.queryForList(query);

        for (Map<String, Object> obj : apoyo) {
            System.out.println(obj.get("nombre"));
            System.out.println(obj.get("correo"));
            System.out.println(obj.get("Telefono"));

            user.setNombre(String.valueOf(obj.get("nombre")));
            user.setCorreo(String.valueOf(obj.get("correo")));
            user.setTelefono(String.valueOf(obj.get("Telefono")));
        }
```