# Arreglos de objetos como compararlos

Tags: java, array, método, bucle-for, imprimir

quisiera saber como puedo hacer que mi método imprimir, imprima el objeto. y lo ejecute en el método burbuja, también agrego mi código de prueba.
Por que lo que me imprime es

> ordenamientos.Persona@15db9742 - ordenamientos.Persona@6d06d69c - ordenamientos.Persona@7852e922 - ordenamientos.Persona@4e25154f - ordenamientos.Persona@70dea4e -

```
public class Ordenamiento <E extends Comparable <E>> {
 private E elementos[];

public Ordenamiento(E [] arreglo){
    elementos =  arreglo;
}

public void imprimir() {
    for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(elementos[i].getClass()+ " - ");
        if (i % 5 == 4) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public void burbuja() {
    for (int i = 1; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < elementos.length - i; j++) {

            if ( (elementos[j].compareTo(elementos[j + 1])) < 0) {
                E aux = elementos[j];
                elementos[j] = elementos[j + 1];
                elementos[j + 1] = aux;

            }
            imprimir();
        }
    }
}
```

CLASE PRUEBA

```
public class TestOrdenamientoG {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Persona[] per = new Persona[5];

    Persona p0 = new Persona("Miguel");
    Persona p1 = new Persona("Vanessa");
    Persona p2 = new Persona("David");
    Persona p3 = new Persona("Jessica");
    Persona p4 = new Persona("Brenda");

    per[0] = p0;
    per[1] = p1;
    per[2] = p2;
    per[3] = p3;
    per[4] = p4;

    Ordenamiento or = new Ordenamiento(per);
    or.burbuja();

    System.out.println(per[0].getNombre());
    System.out.println(per[1].getNombre());
    System.out.println(per[2].getNombre());
    System.out.println(per[3].getNombre());
    System.out.println(per[4].getNombre());
}

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Aunque la pregunta es aceptable para ser la primera, un par de puntos: 1. El código mostrado NO SE CORRESPONDE con el comportamiento descrito (`System.out.print(elementos[i].getClass()+ " - ");` no daría ese resultado); es normal liarse al hacer pruebas pero intenta revisar los datos antes de hacer la pregunta. 2) Tu pregunta en realidad no tiene nada que ver con ordenaciones sino con como imprimir valores de un objeto; intenta acotar bien en tu pregunta cuál es tu problema.

Comment: Y, si buscas por preguntas sobre imprimir listas de objetos, te encuentras que ya hay preguntas con respuestas. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64774/imprimir-lista-de-objetos-en-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que te puede afectar:

1. En el método imprimir:

   System.out.print(elementos[i].getClass()+ " - ");

Quita el  `.getClass()`, ese método te da el nombre de la clase del objeto, busca algún método de la clase persona que te dé el nombre y úsalo ahí.

Saludos.

Comment: elementos[i].getNombre() es lo que debes usar en el imprimir. Y para imprimir en el main or.imprimir(). Ahora, en el ordenamiento al imprimir usa "this.imprimir()". También te recomiendo que cada iteración mandes a imprimir los índices i-j para que veas cómo se mueve el algoritmo.